# How do I load up python in the shell from Vim, but not use it right away?

Tags: python, vim, tdd, maya

I'm doing TDD, but the system I'm working with takes 6 seconds to get through boilerplate code. This code is not part of my work, nor of my tests (it's Autodesk Maya's headless/batch/CLI Python mode). I've talked to support, and there's no way around the load time, so I though maybe I could load and initialize Python first in the background, as I code, and then my mapping would simply run the nosetests inside of that when I'm ready. My tests take something like 0.01 seconds, so this should feel instantaneous, which would really help the red/green/refactor cycle.

In short, instead of firing off `/path/to/mayapy /path/to/runtests.py /current/buffer/path`, Vim would just fire up `/path/to/mayapy` with the boilerplate stuff from `runtests.py`, then somehow hold onto that running instance. When I hit my mapping, it would send into that running instance the call to `nosetest` with the current buffer's path (and then fire up another instance to hold onto while waiting for the next run). How do I hold onto the running instance and call into it later? I'm even considering having a chain of 2 or 3, for the times when I make minor mistakes and rerun 2 seconds later.

Answer (score 2):

[Vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython), the excellent work of Paul Ivanov, is an interface between vim and ipython sessions ([demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngNJyG5e8xY)). This may relieve you of some of the boilerplate of sending buffers to python and waiting on results.

I'm not entirely sure this is exactly what you want, but with a bit of python and vim glue code it may be a good step in the right direction, but I'm guessing you'd need to do a bit of experimentation to get a workflow you're happy with.

Comment: That's cool stuff, but doesn't really answer the question, which is more about interacting with background processes in the shell. I've made some small inroads using `mkfifo`.